Storing hero stats: Database vs ScriptableObject (MOBA game)
What are the pros and cons of storing hero stats (health, velocity, stats for abilities) in a database versus ScriptableObjects for my MOBA-like game? I would like to be able to constantly update hero stats to make adjustmens and change the meta of the game, without players needing to update their game on their mobile devices (since it is a mobile game). I suppose that SOs won't be able to provide that flexibility (in contrast to databases).
While on the other hand, SOs allow designers to easily modify stats through the Inspector, and it's harder to modify data inside databases. I would need to make a custom GUI tool for that, especially since I'm using Firestore, though it won't be that big of a problem to me, since I'm primarily concerned with being able to modify character stats without requiring a new release.
I plan to use a database for other stuff like player account information, statistics, etc. So, what are my options?

Since the data should be stored server side anyway, it does not matter for the player if it gets loaded from a database and sent to the client vs loaded from scriptable object and sent to the client

@Zibelas I'd say that's worth fleshing out into an answer.

@Zibelas You're right. I think that AI chatbots led me into thinking that if I store stats in code (SO assets) users would need to update the app on every modification (as though everything would go into client code). So you're probably implying that SOs are the best place for character stats?

Short answer: Scriptable Objects are probably better.
The long answer. Your client doesnt care. Either with a database or SO you do not need to update each time the client to reflect the new values for your skills or other numerical adjustments. Moba games should be server side validated, any numbers on the client can't be trusted and are therefore just for display. That means you can just sent the numbers once at the start of application with a version number to the client to populate them. This is not a full update, rather a small request to see if the client has the correct numbers.
The real numbers are handled on the server. Now the server does not actually care where you store them. You have to load them anyway. But SO are offering a few advantages over the a database.

A database makes it really hard to reflect the complexity needed in a moba. While certain parameter will be similar (like all heros will be similar in attributes, just different values) - items and skill can't be easily reflected. Active skills on items or unique effects can't easily be done in a database. Spells can be also more complex than just be a cost/ dmg value.
Your SO point is valid that designers can easier manipulate data in the inspector; but it will be more than just data (like sound effects or visual spell effects) than can be adjusted and stored

